# How to step into a Task result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I am looking into the following solution: https://github.com/grandchamp/Identity.Dapper and what this solution does is, it combines Dapper, Identity Core and MVC Frameworks. However, this solution for Identity Core less than 2.0. So I want to use the project but I want to upgrade it to 2.0. When I do that, I encounter errors and my problem is that I can't get the error to find out what is wrong.

Please consider the following code:

```
public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    if (user == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

    user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

This is stored in src/Identity.Dapper/Stores/DapperUserStore.cs and it is called when Creating a new user. However, this is the first time I have ever seen code in such a manner. If I try to step into any of this, it doesn't work (and I have the source code of the entire project in my solution).

My question is: how to debug such a code so that I can access that Data Layer and get the actual problem.